# Fullcalendar Scheduler Timeline Print Issue

Tags: css, printing, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Scheduler Fullcalendar timeline view doesn't REALLY support printing at all but unfortunately my client needs it. The issue is that the latter half of the calendar is getting cut off in print.

The potential solutions: Using `zoom: 0.8` works amazing in Chrome and all the days of the week appear. However that doesn't do anything for Firefox. `transform: scale(0.8)` doesn't seem to have the same effect as part of calendar is still cut off, though it's all scaled down. If I emulate css in Chrome it shows up even with the transform scale toggled on, however does not show up in actual print.

Please excuse the potato styling of the calendar when it prints. I'm more concerned with friday the latter half of the calendar being cut off. In chrome toggle my comment for zoom and switch to scale to see the difference.

Here is codepen link https://codepen.io/bedelman851/pen/wXeZEO

Comment: have you tried combining it with fullcalendar's ready-made print CSS? You can add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.print.min.css" media="print" />` to your page. Perhaps that would help. But really web pages in general are not particular made for printing - they are not constrained by the size of pieces of paper. Your client could always print on bigger paper if they can...I assume you're already using landscape view? What about making the global font-size smaller? Just some ideas off the top of my head.

Comment: @ADyson yeah I have included that in the codepen as well. I could mess with the font size though it's already pretty small. They may just have to use chrome only (in a perfect world) to print this calendar. It's an internal product so there's at least a chance of that. I have felt like such a css noob working on printing this view. Up is down and left is right.

Comment: @BrianEdelman Did you try css 

.fc-scroller {
    margin: 0px !important;
}

 suggested @ https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/issues/185

Comment: This resolved issue of timeline in IE but I am not able to print complete timeline. Timeline truncated at 9pm

Comment: Was there ever any solution to this? Working on it myself at the moment...

Comment: @MiskaRantala No unfortunately. I hacked the crap out of the css to get it to print but I can't remember how successful I was. Take a look at this package https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ as I remember it being a really helpful potential solution. But I don't have that installed in the project so I think i just used css. Leaving an answer on this question with all my css for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

I've been away from this project for a while and I don't think I solved this satisfactorily but I did solve it to be "good enough" for my situation. I looked into lots of options and spent way too much time on it.

The css I ended up going with is below. I can't vouch for how it looks or what you need, but if it's helpful then I am glad!

```
 //CALENDAR CSS
  .calendar-functions,
  .calendar-functions div:last-child,
  .calendar-functions a,
  .calendar-view h1,
  .fc-right,
  .fc-right button,
  .fc-license-message,
  .print-button,
  .print-button-week {
    display: none;
  }


  .month-view .calendar-functions div,
  .week-view .calendar-functions div {
    display: none;
  }

  .fc-event:after {
    content: attr(data-coll) !important;
  }

  .fc-body {
    height: 400px !important;
  }

  .calendar-widget-week,
  .fc-timeline {
    width: 100%;
  }

  body {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .fc-view-container {
    // transform: scale(0.8);
    zoom: 0.8;
  }

  .fc-timeline {

    th {
      height: 30px;
    }

    .fc-scroller-canvas {
      min-width: 100% !important;
      width: 100% !important;
    }
  }


  .calendar-day tr td:first-child {
    a[href]:after {
      display: none;
    }
  }

  .fc {
    max-width: 100% !important;

    th {
      height: 30px;
    }
  }

  .fc-event {
    background: transparent !important;
    color: #000 !important;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }

  .fc-event .fc-resizer {
    display: none;
  }

  .fc th,
  .fc td,
  .fc hr,
  .fc thead,
  .fc tbody,
  .fc-row {
    border-color: #ccc !important;
  }

  .fc-bgevent-skeleton,
  .fc-highlight-skeleton,
  .fc-helper-skeleton,
  .fc-business-container,
  .fc-highlight-container,
  .fc-helper-container {
    display: none;
  }

  .fc-ltr .fc-timeline-event {
    margin-right: 5px;
  }

  .calendar-widget-week .fc-timeline-event {
    padding-bottom: 97px;
  }

  /* don't force a min-height on rows (for DayGrid) */
  .fc tbody .fc-row {
    height: auto !important;
    /* undo height that JS set in distributeHeight */
    min-height: 0 !important;
/* undo the min-height from each view's specific stylesheet */ }

  .fc tbody .fc-row .fc-content-skeleton {
    position: static;
    /* undo .fc-rigid */
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
/* use a more border-friendly method for this... */ }

  .fc tbody .fc-row .fc-content-skeleton tbody tr:last-child td {
    /* only works in newer browsers */
    padding-bottom: 1em;
/* ...gives space within the skeleton. also ensures min height in a way */ }

  .fc tbody .fc-row .fc-content-skeleton table {
    /* provides a min-height for the row, but only effective for IE, which exaggerates this value,
     making it look more like 3em. for other browers, it will already be this tall */
    height: 1em; }

  //List views
  .pagination-right,
  .pagination-left *,
  .pagination-right *,
  .pagination-left {
    display: none;
  }

  .fc-day-grid-event,
  .fc-timeline-event {
    &:before {
      content: attr(data-id);

    }
    &:after {
      content: "";
    }

    &:before,
    &:after {
      display: inline-block !important;
    }
  }

  .fc-scroller {
    overflow: visible !important;

    .fc-scroller-canvas {
      min-width: none !important;
    }
  }

  @page :left {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  @page :right {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  /* for vertical events */
  .fc-event-bg {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .fc-event .ui-resizable-handle {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .print-window__exit {
    display: none;
  }

  #calendar-week {
    display: none;
  }

  .dt-print-view {
    #calendar-week {
      display: block;
    }
  }

  .print-table,
  .print-title {
    display: block !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked from me on Chrome and Edge (Firefox is still working too)

```
@media print {
    body {
        zoom: 0.8;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).